# Google Sheets Query - How to return part of String?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the following formula, to successfully retrieve data.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...);"select Col5, Col1, Col2 where Col2!=''";FALSE)
```

The data in Col2 are strings that look like this: `A thing - something - some other thing`

Only the part before the first occurence of `-` is of interest; but I'm having trouble only returning this part of the string.

When I use the following formula on one of the strings, I get the desired result:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("A thing - something - some other thing";"^[^-]*")
```

I'm not sure how to combine the formula's however; or if this is even the right way to go about this?
All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column applying REGEXEXTRACT (with the help of BYROW to do it sequentially) and then use that inside the QUERY.

I'll use LET so it's easier to see the process:

```
=LET(imported,IMPORTRANGE(...),
     newcol,BYROW(INDEX(imported,,2),LAMBDA(each,REGEXEXTRACT(each;"^[^-]*"))),
     QUERY({imported,newcol},"select Col5,Col1,Col6 where Col6!=''",0))
```

I'm assuming that your imported range has 5 columns, so the new one is the 6th; please adapt it if necessary

Comment: I had one comma put instead of semi colon. Try again and let me know!

Comment: LET allows you to sequentiate your process of calculations by setting names to the different results of your steps. First I imported the range, then I created the new column, and then I used the QUERY with that range made by joining those two previous steps

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This solution works perfectly, and will help me in the future as well; thanks again!